# How to keep custom moqui components in a separate directory

Tags: moqui

Suppose I wish to put my custom components in a directory named 'cc', which will sit next to the 'moqui-trunk' directory.

`dev/
 |-- cc/
 |-- moqui-trunk/`

There's a setting in MoquiInit.properties
`moqui.runtime=../moqui/runtime`

One would ideally think that changing this to `../cc` should do the job. But underneath there's another block, which says:
`if there is a "runtime" directory in the war file (in the root of the webapp) that will be used instead of this setting`

I think if I rename/delete the 'runtime' directory in the 'moqui-trunk' directory, then it would start picking components from my 'cc' directory. But how can I achieve the same with minimum changes in the 'moqui-trunk' (so as to easily manage patches, svn update etc).

Answer (score 1):

I am not following why you would want to move things around but the way I do it is to have three git repos a) Moqui b) Mantle c) Components

- Moqui is git cloned to /moqui
- Mantle is git cloned to /moqui/runtime/mantle
- Components is git cloned to /moqui/runtime/component

In my components is where I have subdirectories for my applications and all this means that I can keep everything clean and as close to upstream as possible and it also means that if you are in /moqui directory you can git pull for upstream Moqui changes and same goes for /moqui/runtime/mantle for Mantle changes.

Also have a look at the [Making Apps with Moqui](http://www.moqui.org/MakingAppsWithMoqui-1.0.pdf) book it really helps explain the basics of building atop of Moqui.